# toString() as property descriptor in Object having a NULL prototype

Tags: javascript

In one of the JavaScript tutorial I found an task as below:

> There’s an object dictionary, created as Object.create(null), to store any key/value pairs.

> Add method dictionary.toString() into it, that should return a comma-delimited list of keys. Your toString should not show up in for..in over the object.

The solution for the task is

```js
let dictionary = Object.create(null, {
  toString: { // define toString property
    value() { // the value is a function
      return Object.keys(this).join(',');
    }
  }
});

dictionary.apple = "Apple";
dictionary.__proto__ = "test";

// apple and __proto__ is in the loop
for(let key in dictionary) {
  alert(key); // "apple", then "__proto__"
}

// comma-separated list of properties by toString
alert(dictionary); // "apple,__proto__"
```

Why the function `value()` is required and if I give other name in place of `value()` it gives an error **toString() is not a Function**

Comment: Because that's how property descriptors for functions work?

Comment: You could just change it to `let dictionary = Object.create(null, {
  toString: function(){
    return Object.keys(this).join(',');
  }
});`

Comment: You can find more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)
You can define toString as a normal function as well and it's working even if value is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use `value` option to set value for the property. In this case, its name is `toString`.

Since you declare the value option with syntax:

```
value () {
  //
}
```

It's as same as

```
value: function () {
  //
}
```

BTW, `value` is a function. And because this option will be applied to `toString` propperty. So, `toString` is a function, too.

```js
let dictionary = Object.create(null, {
  toString: {
    value() {
      return this;
    },
    /* same to */
    value: function () {
      return this;
    }
  }
});

console.log(typeof dictionary.toString);
```

So, if we change the returned type of `value` to a string, the returned type of `toString` property will be changed, too:

```js
let dictionary = Object.create(null, {
  toString: {
    value: 'This is dictionary object'
  }
});

console.log(dictionary.toString);
```

---

In ES6, you can use `set` and `get` keywords to do that:

```js
let _value;

let dictionary = Object.create(null, {
  toString: {
    get () {
      // return value
      return "Language: " + _value;
    },
    set (value) {
      // set value to a temporary variable:
      _value = value;
    }
  }
});

// now, we try to define "toString" property:
dictionary.toString = 'en';

// output: "Language: en"
console.log(dictionary.toString);
```